Efficient way to compute gradients separately w.r.t each class in Pytorch
I am trying to compute the gradients of a Pytorch image classifier model separately with respect to each class, for example
outputs = net(inputs)[0] # assuming we only consider the first sample of the batch
grads = [torch.autograd.grad(outputs[i], inputs, retain_graph=True) 
         for i in range(len(outputs))]

However, in torch.autograd.grad documentation, it states
'''
Note that in nearly all cases setting this option (retain_graph) to True is not needed and often can be worked around in a much more efficient way
'''

Bing AI has suggested to use
identity = torch.eye(len(outputs))
outputs.backward(gradient=identity)

But it obviously does not work
RuntimeError: Mismatch in shape: grad_output[0] has a shape of torch.Size([9, 9]) and outputs has a shape of torch.Size([9]).

(Here the image classifer has 9 classes)

I am therefore wondering whether there is a more efficient way in this case, and if so, how to implement it?
Thanks for any helps!

have you tried other libraries other than pytorch?

Refering GPT's suggestion, maybe repeating the output to match the shape outputs.repeat(9, 1).backward(gradient=identity) can help?

"can be worked around in a much more efficient way", depends on what you want to do with this model gradient? What are your intentions?

Thanks for all the above comments and helps.
The entire wider framework is on Pytorch, and the model is Pytorch, so I may have to stick with it.
I have tried outputs.repeat(9, 1).backward(gradient=identity) before, but it would give grad of shape [1, original_input_shape], whereas I am expecting to get 9 sets of gradients: [9, original_input_shape] (one w.r.t each class),
I am wondering whether this can be done in a quicker way, without calling autograd.grad 9 times?

The issue you're running into in outputs.backward(gradient=identity) is because identity is the wrong shape.
usually the argument to gradient should be the same shape as the tensor you are calling backward on. I say usually because technically a.backward(gradient=b) computes b^T @ Jacobian(a) so it depends on the shape of the Jacobian, but usually when you're calling backward on the output of a model you want the same shape.
This is the standard way to call backward on a vector output:
x = torch.randn(32, 4)
model = nn.Linear(4, 2)
y = model(x)

input_grad = torch.ones_like(y) # create vector of ones the same shape as y
y.backward(input_grad)
model.weight.grad

> tensor([[ 1.1243,  2.3456,  2.3656, -8.8384],
          [ 1.1243,  2.3456,  2.3656, -8.8384]])

If you want to mask parts of your output from the gradient calculation, you can set the relevant input_grad values to 0.
For example, this masks the second column of the output tensor:
x = torch.randn(32, 4)
model = nn.Linear(4, 2)
y = model(x)

input_grad = torch.ones_like(y) # create vector of ones the same shape as y
input_grad[:,1] = 0. # mask the second column of the output

y.backward(input_grad)

# masking changes gradient output
model.weight.grad

> tensor([[ 1.1243,  2.3456,  2.3656, -8.8384],
          [ 0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000]])

This example only backprops through the first four items in the batch:
x = torch.randn(32, 4)
model = nn.Linear(4, 2)
y = model(x)

input_grad = torch.ones_like(y) # create vector of ones the same shape as y
input_grad[4:] = 0. # only backprop through the first 4 items in the batch

y.backward(input_grad)

# masking changes gradient output
model.weight.grad

> tensor([[-0.2436,  0.8189, -0.1244, -0.4814],
          [-0.2436,  0.8189, -0.1244, -0.4814]])

To backprop from a specific slice, take the slice and use a ones tensor of the same shape:
x = torch.randn(32, 4)
model = nn.Linear(4, 2)
y = model(x)

y_slice = y[7] # grab specific batch item

input_grad = torch.ones_like(y_slice) # create vector of ones the same shape as y_slice

y_slice.backward(input_grad)

model.weight.grad

> tensor([[-0.1745, -1.1161, -0.8109, -0.6540],
          [-0.1745, -1.1161, -0.8109, -0.6540]])

Now to your example of computing the gradients of different classes with respect to the input, you can do something like this:
# inputs must have `requires_grad=True` if you want to backprop into them
x = torch.randn(32, 4, requires_grad=True)

# model has two output classes
model = nn.Linear(4, 2)

# y is size `(32, 2)` for 32 batch items and 2 classes
y = model(x)

grads = []

for batch_idx in range(x.shape[0]): # iterate over batch items
    for class_idx in range(y.shape[1]): # iterate over classes
        y_slice = y[batch_idx, class_idx] # get specific output value

        # compute grad with retain graph
        # note that the second argument must be `x`, you cannot 
        # pass a slice of `x` because it was not used in the 
        # compute graph that produced `y`
        grad = torch.autograd.grad(y_slice, x, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(y_slice), retain_graph=True)
        
        # grad output is a tulple of shape `(grad,)
        # grad[0] grabs the actual grad tensor
        # the grad tensor is the same shape of `x`, but due to backproping from y_slice,
        # all items except `batch_idx` are zero.
        # `grad[0][batch_idx]` gets the gradient specifically of item `batch_idx` wrt `class_idx`
        grad = grad[0][batch_idx]
        
        # save tuple of batch_idx, class_idx, grad
        grads.append((batch_idx, class_idx, grad))

For a fun exercise, run the code above and look at the gradients for each class:
print([i[-1] for i in grads if i[1]==0])
print([i[-1] for i in grads if i[1]==1])

You'll notice the gradient values are the same for each input item with respect to a given class. Think about why this makes sense.
